# What is friction head loss through a pipe mean?

Tags: thermodynamics

If water goes through a pipe and ends up at higher elevation, what does it mean for the water to have friction head loss?

Comment: What formula do you think you need to use?  What have you tried and why isn't it working?  Homework questions are allowed at this SE site, but you need to demonstrate a measure of effort beyond what you've shown so far.  The community is happy to help with specific issues on a specific problem, but we're not here to do your homework for you.  Please [edit] your question to show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

In simplest terms to convey a volume of fluid through a pipe some amount of energy is required. A part of this energy is lost to the resistance to flow. When a fluid flows through the pipe, it encounters resistance and head loss due to shear stresses (within the fluid) and turbulence at boundary with pipe wall( depending on surface roughness). This resistance measured in meters (head) of the fluid is the frictional head loss.
You can use the Darcy-Weisbach equation in conjunction with Moody chart to find friction factor and head loss due to friction in pipe run. You also can account for pressure drop and frictional losses due to changes in direction in pipe bends and fittings (using manufacturer's k factors)